# matrix multiplication in simulink

Tags: matrix, simulink

I am using simulink and I want to modify a signal using a matrix: what is the tool to obtain a block containing the matrix.
Furthermore I would like to import the matrix from the workspace.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what modification you want to make: do you want to extract columns/rows, change columns/rows, perform a math operation...???  You can import a matrix from the MATLAB Workspace using the Constant block (by changing the default block options)

Comment: What I want is exactly like a matrix transfer function that takes as input n signals and returns m signals. In my case by the way I am interested just in a specific frequency so ma matrix transfer function becomes a numerical complex valued matrix

Answer (score 2):

For multiplying Matrix you can use [*product*](http://www.mathworks.in/help/simulink/slref/product.html) block, where can either do element-wise or matrix multiplication

[image]

For choosing data from workspace follow following example :

```
>> t1 = [1 :1:10]'; % for simulation time
>> m = magic(2); % Your matrix to be multipied
>> M = repmat(m,[1 1 length(t1)]); % repeat for length(t1) times
>> data.time = t1;
>> data.signals.values = M;
>> data.signals.dimensions =[2 2]; % Dimension of matrix
```

Now use `data` in the [*From Workspace*](http://www.mathworks.in/help/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html) block, as show in above snapshot.

Comment: Thanks but what I meant that I have n input signals that are multiplied by a numerical matrix to get m output signals. It is like a frequency transfer matrix but at one specific frequency (so that it is a complex valued matrix)

Comment: @checcohotantasete Read your question again, does that mention anything that's not answered ? PS: I don't have psychic power to know what you actually meant. Also as per your new question, I'd suggest to use appropriate block to get "m" outputs, here I just use a display to illustrate the output.

Comment: Did I say you did not answer or pretending your answer to be exactly what I meant?
I was just specifying further my question what I meant since it is not easy to explain.
Thanks anyway

Comment: @checcohotantasete Agreed , but if you'd have clarified it _somewhat_ as you did [one day after](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697486/matrix-multiplication-in-simulink/24703129?noredirect=1#comment38329192_24697486), we wouldn't be having this worthless chat, since I didn't have answer and show some efforts, chill & cheers !